# Sorting TreeMaps by value

Tags: java, sorting, generics, treemap

I'm looking to sort a TreeMap of Customer objects by a specific Customer property.
The TreeMap is defined as so:

```
private TreeMap<Long,Customer> customerMap = new TreeMap<>();
```

Long is the type of ID for the customers stored.

I wrote a function to create a new TreeMap and pass a Comparator to its constructor which gets map entries, their values, that compares the specific field.

```
public Customer[] getCustomersByName() {
    TreeMap<Long,Customer> sortByName = new TreeMap<> (

        new Comparator<Map.Entry<Long,Customer>>() {
            @Override public int compare(Map.Entry<Long,Customer> cus1, Map.Entry<Long,Customer> cus2) {
                return cus1.getValue().getLastName().compareTo(cus2.getValue().getLastName());
            }
        }
    );
    sortByName.putAll(customerMap);
    
    // sortByName to Customer[] and return.

}
```

This doesn't work and throws: Cannot infer type arguments for TreeMap<>Java(16778094) at Line 2.

Perhaps, the issue is that the Comparator takes <Map.Entry<K,V>> to compare a TreeMap<K,V> and that is the issue.

How would I fix this though to sort by values but keep the customerMap type as is?

I know that TreeMaps are only sorted by keys. Is there a better data structure for this job perhaps so that I could store a bunch of Customer objects and sort them by different Customer properties without the operation being too expensive (not polynomial preferably)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up a second TreeMap, using the customers last name as the key:

```
TreeMap<String,Customer> sortByName  = new TreeMap<>();
TreeMap<Long,Customer> sortByID = new TreeMap<>();
----------------
sortByName.put(customer.getLastName(), customer);
sortByID.put(new Long(customer.getID()), customer);
----------------
return sortByName.values().toArray( new Customer[sortByName.size()] );
'''
```

Comment: but why? the result OP is after is a sorted `Customer[]`, it is way easier to achieve this

Comment: @Eugene Easier in which way? Both a second TreeMap (sorted by the lastName) and the streams achieve the same result, albeit using different methodology.

Comment: this is a matter of perspective indeed, but if you plan to go to the moon by making a circle around Jupiter, then I find it too much. I don't mind that, the view might be fabulous, that is just too much for the goal.

Comment: @Eugene That's kind of snarky... There is nothing wrong with a loop to fill a TreeMap, then extract an array from the values. Just because ```stream``` is the latest toy, does not mean is has to be fit into everything.

Comment: right. that is exactly the reason I did not downvote. I only commented. I should have made it clear, that it is my opinion only. It is up to the OP to choose. And it turns out the OP is more inclined to use your version, according to his/her requirements..

Comment: Why fill two `TreeMap`s when one of them is entirely unused? By the way, you should not specify a size to the array passed to `toArray`. Use `sortByName.values().toArray( new Customer[0] )`. Specifying a size is a premature optimization based on assumptions. If you want to know the actual outcome, read [this excellent article](https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/arrays-wisdom-ancients/). The fastest sorting is, by the way, `Customer[] array = map.values().toArray(new Customer[0]); Arrays.sort(array, Comparator.comparing(Customer::getLastName)); return array;`

Comment: @Holger Well the excellent article, in the API Design section states the exact opposite. It is better to allocate an array using the Collection size, rather than an empty array. That way you only allocate one array, rather than allocating an empty array, then having the``` toArray()``` method allocating the array which is passed back. And the ```Specifying a size is a premature optimization based on assumptions``` is actually solid, as it is extremely unlikely that the collection size will change between the ```size()``` call and the filling of the array.

Comment: @Holger Using two TreeMap is based on the assumption that there is a need to look at the data in two different ways. The OP needs sorting by last name, and the sorting by ID. The cost is minimal as it is only the TreeMap allocation, plus a reference per Customer object. Usually in this type of operation (yes, I assume...), the TreeMap is filled from persistent storage once, with CRUD happening on user actions.

Comment: @BigGuy It seems, you have difficulties with reading and understanding an article. It does *not* say that pre-sizing an array was better; it clearly says that tools like IntelliJ IDEA 15 and PMD 5.4.1 made such claims and then proceed with verifying those claims  (which is what this entire article is about) and find them wrong. Since the authors of those tools did read and understand the article after it was published, their recent versions do not suggest that anymore but rather suggest to use a zero sized array.

Comment: @Holger Quit trying to insult me... Yes the article does in fact, after extensive analysis, conclude that a zero based array is faster. But it also states that this is silliness, that premature optimization is a waste of time. Only with clearly defined performance criteria should this type of analysis be performed, and moreover with people who know how to analyze performance issues at that level. The 2016 article also states that VM development may swing the analysis the other way. The difference is around 30 nano-seconds per operation (on a list size of 100).

Comment: Now that you understood that using a zero sized array is actually faster, (and it’s worth noting that nothing has changed, that’s why the latest addition, [`Collection.toArray(IntFunction)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#toArray(java.util.function.IntFunction)) just creates a zero sized array and delegates to `toArray(T[])`, as even noted in the documentation), we can come to the most relevant thing: **`collection.toArray(new Type[0])` is simpler and less error prone than `collection.toArray(new Type[collection.size()])`**.

Answer (score 0):

This is rather easy with streams:

```
Customer[] cust =
    customerMap.values()
               .stream()
               .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Customer::getName))
               .toArray(Customer[]::new);
```

You only need to sort the *values* according to your example, so why bother sorting the `TreeMap` in reverse, when the only thing you care about is a sorted (by name) `Customer[]`?

Comment: Thanks for this. I did everything I did because I'm actually assigned some project by a data structures class and the use of Collections is restricted. I'm required to implement the structure and sort it by scratch. I figured treemaps would be a good idea since they would already be sorted by natural order after putting the objects in. I did forget though, I could only sort by keys using comparators. @Big Guy 's response could be more suitable in this case but I want something more concise and would like to avoid wasting space also. Would you have any recommendations in my case here?

Comment: @sealion One of the problems with being too **consise** is that you create write-only code. It looks good when you write it, but coming back later to edit it becomes a problem. Even though some of my code may be wordy, it is (should be) readily understandable later on. With the odd comment of course :-)